# Como faço para usar a tag video no firefox ou Chrome

Tags: html5, vídeo

Estou tentando e não consigo visualizar o vídeo no meu sistema, pegando do `C:/`, está funcionando somente no Internet Explore. Segue o código:

```
<video width="320" src="C:\video\ninguemFerro.mov" height="240" controls="controls" type="video/mov; codecs=dirac, speex">< /video>
```

Comment: Aperte F12 e depois F5, olhe na aba Console qual foi o erro que apareceu

Comment: humm boa, diz que é não é permitido exibir um arquivo local

Comment: Abrir no Firefox e Opera e o video rodou normalmente, estou usando Win8.1, tem como você copiar exatamente a frase de erro que aparece no console do seu navegador?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que esse formato de vídeo (.mov) não é suportado.
Cada navegador suporta um formato de vídeo específico, mas basicamente são 3:

- .ogg
- .WebM
- .mp4

A relação entre o formato de vídeo e vavegador pode ser encontrada na seção "HTML Video - Browser Support" na [w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp).

Comment: opa obrigado por ajuda, mais ja tentei todos estes tipos e mesmo assim não vai, só funiciona normal no browser edge e I.E

Comment: O vídeo foi convertido para um dos formatos citados? ou você apenas alterou a extensão?

Comment: foi convertido, os que testei foram, Mp4, WebM, Mov, M4v

Comment: No meu Firefox e Opera funcionou, mas talvez seja porque eu tenha instalado o QuickTime na máquina e tenha com isto usado os CODECs do sistema.